# How to set a custom website name instead of ip address for local computer?

Tags: virtualhost

I can point a url to a directory in my computer by setting /etc/host and /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf files. For instance, when i type sample-app.com in my computer, website under /Users/azad/works/sample-app.com folder is running.

When someone type sample-app.com in another computer in same local network i want to display the same website located on my computer. Is this possible?

By the way, i don't have access to any computer in the local network and i can't do any configuration.

Mac 10.7.5 (I am using mac but if windows is better for this purpose i can use windows too),
PHP 5.3,
Apache 2.2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accomplish this on windows, use the hosts file on the computers you want to point at that sample-app.com URL mapping your IP address to that URL in all the computers you want that to work on. Then make sure your HTTP server is configured to serve that website under that host name for port 80.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont have access to computers

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't able to configure the local network, the best way to handle this situation is to configure a host name with the website domain's DNS server, such as dev.sample-app.com, which points to the local IP address (seeing as how its on the local network) of the computer hosting the website. This will then allow other computers on the local network to enter this host name to access the webiste.

If you had control of the local network's DNS server or control of the proxy (if they have a proxy), there would, of course, be other options.

**Update:**
Since you mentioned in your comment that you have control over the DNS server, here is how you could accomplish your goal via the DNS server. First, add a forward lookup zone for `sample-app.com` to the DNS server. Second, configure the default host for the zone to point to the computer serving up the website content. Now the client computers will resolve the local IP when the user enters `sample-app.com` into their web browsers. If you need to continue to have access to other hosts on sample-app.com, you might want to try asking about it on serverfault.

Comment: I dont have access to only client computers, but i have rights to configure servers and local network.

Comment: Sorry i am not good in hosting stuffs, DNS servers etc. Do i need to install a DNS server? If yes then could you please send a link about how to set a DNS server for this purpose?

Comment: Thanks @Fls'Zen, i am newbie for DNS server. I will do some research for how to install and configure DNS server based on your answer.